# How to ignore the password field while updating if the field is empty?

Tags: php, pdo, sql-update

I am editing the admin details and it's working but I am getting one issue on password.

My issue is If the password field is empty then still updating the existing password and I am getting the empty data in the database.

What I want, if there is data in the password field then update it or else ignore the password field while updating.

I am using below code

```
function updateAdmin($pdo){
$a_firstname=sanitize_data($_POST['editfirstname']);
$a_lastname=sanitize_data($_POST['editlastname']);
$a_email=$_POST['editemail'];
$a_accessrole=sanitize_data($_POST['editaccessrole']);
$admin_id=sanitize_data($_POST['admin_id']);

if(!empty($_POST['editpassword'])){
    $a_password=sanitize_data($_POST['editpassword']);
    $password=password_hash($a_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT,['cost' => 12]);
}

  $data=array(
     'a_firstname' => $a_firstname,  
    'a_lastname' => $a_lastname,   
    'a_email' => $a_email,    
    'a_password' => $password,
    'a_accessrole' => $a_accessrole
      );
try{
  
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_admin SET a_firstname=:a_firstname, a_lastname=:a_lastname, a_email=:a_email, a_password=:a_password, a_accessrole=:a_accessrole WHERE admin_id=:admin_id";

$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam('admin_id', $admin_id);
$stmt->execute($data);

    $response['error'] = "true";

 } catch(PDOExecption $e) { 
        $dbh->rollback(); 
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>"; 
        $response['error'] = "false";
    } 
    // print_r($response);
    echo json_encode($response);
}




function sanitize_data($data)
 {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = strip_tags($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;    
 }
```

Comment: "*if there is data in the password field then update it or else ignore the password field while updating.*" ... I suggest doing exactly that. Nothing prevents you from creating one or another sql string.

Comment: Side note: I don't know what `sanitize_data()` does, but it's certainly either unnecessary or corrupts input data.

Comment: Agree with @ÁlvaroGonzález ... you should never alter a person's input password in anyway. Using `password_hash` and `password_verify` negates reasons to sanitize it. What if I wanted to actually put `<script>alert('opensesame!');</script>` as my password?

Comment: @IncredibleHat, Apologizes for the late reply. I added the sanitize_data() function in the question. Please check it once.

Comment: @user9437856 You DEFINITELY do not want to be using that `sanitize_data()` on a users password input. Heck, I even question that `htmlspecialchars()` bit for the other fields before input into a database. In general you store data as it *should be*, then when you *display it*, you wrap it in htmlspecialchars (as its intended to display data safely in... html).

Comment: @IncredibleHat, I got your point, I removed sanitize_data from the password. I just want to know what are the input field we can  sanitize_data? One of my fried suggest me don't use with Email, now you suggest me with password. Is there any thing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the goal with a slightly modification in your php code. So rather than using fixed table column and SQL params to update the table, check the $_POST['editaccessrole'] and construct param and UPDATE SQL dynamically. Hope below code will work for you.

```
function updateAdmin($pdo) {
    $a_firstname = sanitize_data($_POST['editfirstname']);
    $a_lastname = sanitize_data($_POST['editlastname']);
    $a_email = $_POST['editemail'];
    $a_accessrole = sanitize_data($_POST['editaccessrole']);
    $admin_id = sanitize_data($_POST['admin_id']);

    $data = array('a_firstname' => $a_firstname, 'a_lastname' => $a_lastname, 'a_email' => $a_email, 'a_accessrole' => $a_accessrole);
    $password_sql = "";
    if (isset($_POST['editpassword']) && !empty($_POST['editpassword'])) {
        //Add the a_password column in UPDATE statement if edit password value is set and non empty
        $a_password = sanitize_data($_POST['editpassword']);
        $password=password_hash($a_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT,['cost' => 12]);
        
        //So the parm and SQL is dynamic based on $_POST['editpassword']
        $data['a_password'] = $password;
        $password_sql = ", a_password=:a_password";
    }

    try {

        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_admin SET a_firstname=:a_firstname, a_lastname=:a_lastname, a_email=:a_email{$password_sql}, a_accessrole=:a_accessrole WHERE admin_id=:admin_id";

        $stmt = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
        $stmt -> bindParam('admin_id', $admin_id);
        $stmt -> execute($data);
        //This is success but you are sending true as error, any particular reason? I hope you did it intentionally.
        $response['error'] = "true";

    } catch(PDOExecption $e) {
        $dbh -> rollback();
        print "Error!: " . $e -> getMessage() . "</br>";
        //This is failed but you are sending false as error, any particular reason? I hope you did it intentionally.
        $response['error'] = "false";
    }
    // print_r($response);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: I think your solution is working for me. Let me try again and confirm

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned *What I want, if there is data in the password field then update it or else ignore the password field while updating.*. In this case, you can use an `if` condition in the SQL query like below:

```
UPDATE tbl_admin 
SET a_firstname = :a_firstname, 
    a_lastname = :a_lastname, 
    a_email = :a_email, 
    a_password = if(a_password is null or length(a_password) = 0,a_password,:a_password), 
    a_accessrole = :a_accessrole 
WHERE admin_id = :admin_id
```

**Update:**

If you meant it from empty password field from post request, you can first set appropriate data for query placeholders like below:

```
$data = array(
    'a_firstname' => $a_firstname,  
    'a_lastname' => $a_lastname,   
    'a_email' => $a_email,    
    'a_password' => empty(trim($a_password)) ? '' : $password,
    'a_accessrole' => $a_accessrole
);
```

And your SQL query would be like below:

```
UPDATE tbl_admin 
SET a_firstname = :a_firstname, 
    a_lastname = :a_lastname, 
    a_email = :a_email, 
    a_password = if(length(:a_password) = 0,a_password,:a_password), 
    a_accessrole = :a_accessrole 
WHERE admin_id = :admin_id
```

Comment: I am also using the if condition. Can I remove that?

Comment: Yes, looks like.

Comment: Give me some time to implement this.

Comment: I checked and if the password is empty it's not updating my password which is correct but when I add the password then it's updating the password which is also correct but I am getting zero(0) in the database. https://prnt.sc/tjq12a

Comment: I think there is some issue with query. It's not uodating when there is data in the password.

Comment: What is that 0? I hope the $password has the actual hash value.

Comment: @user9437856 Which version of my answer are you trying?

Comment: I tried Update one. I am getting the $data output
Array
(
    [a_firstname] => test
    [a_lastname] => test
    [a_email] => test@gmail.com
    [a_password] => $2y$12$yRRag4zj/0cB/8m3ggd0n.CzGMgNVwXUjd1tXzBs5mJ0ez/AgV3me
    [a_accessrole] => 1
)

Comment: @user9437856 What happens if you run the raw SQL with the condition?

Comment: @user9437856 My steps worked perfectly fine on my machine :)